# How to bind sockets in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm tring to use ruby Socket class directly, TCPSocket is not an option.
Code:

```
require 'socket'
include Socket::Constants

socket = Socket.new :INET, :STREAM, 0
socket.bind (Socket.pack_sockaddr_in 2200, 'localhost')
```

Error:

> `bind': An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.
> (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 in a Windows machine.

Extra info:

> Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(2200, 'localhost')
>
> => "\x17\x00\b\x98\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00"

Hosts file:

> # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
> #    127.0.0.1       localhost
> #    ::1             localhost

Comment: I think there's something funky about the address returned in Windows with `Socket.pack_sockaddr_in 2200, 'localhost'` .  This is what mine returns on linux `=> "\x02\x00\b\x98\x7F\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"`

Comment: @Rico I added the output of sockaddr_in to my question. Comparing it with yours, it has less bytes. Could it be an IPV4, IPV6 mismatch?

Comment: yeah, try what I put in my answer.

Comment: @texasbruce Added what's in my hosts file to the question. 2 entries there, but commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
require 'socket'
include Socket::Constants

socket = Socket.new :INET, :STREAM, 0
socket.bind (Socket.pack_sockaddr_in 2200, '127.0.0.1')
```

Could be that `localhost` is returning your IPv6 address and not taking it.

Comment: @SlySherZ If this works for you, you need to check your host file. It may miss localhost entry or it is pointing to other address (e.g.IP6 address)

Comment: Yeah and also check what `dig localhost` returns.  Not sure of `dig` works on Windows (equivalent of nslookup)

Comment: I got back an IPV6 from that query.

Comment: In that case `socket = Socket.new(:INET6, :STREAM, 0)` would also work with `localhost`